# Can I instantiate or produce an enum value from the enum name and the value's rawValue at runtime in Swift?

Tags: enums, swift5

We are using Swift 5.0. I need to turn a list of strings into a set of enum cases regularly. I wrote a Kotlin function easily that takes an enum class at runtime and a list of strings, and converts it to a Java `EnumSet` (well, 2 functions that work together):

```
fun <EnumT : Enum<EnumT>> ConvertStrToEnum(enumClass: Class<EnumT>, str: String?): EnumT? {
    if (str == null)
        return null
    for (enumval in enumClass.enumConstants) {
        if (enumval.toString() == str)
            return enumval
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Gave an invalid enum value for class ${enumClass.canonicalName}: [$str]")
}

fun <EnumT : Enum<EnumT> > ConvertStrArrayToEnumSet(enumClass: Class<EnumT>, array: List<String>?) : EnumSet<EnumT> {
    val set = EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass)
    array?.forEach { value -> ignoreExceptions { set.add(ConvertStrToEnum(enumClass, value)) } }
    return set
}
```

And, to be clear, an actual usage is:

```
var intent: EnumSet<Intent>
intent = ConvertStrArrayToEnumSet(Intent::class.java, filters.array(MatchFilter.Intent.jsonName))
```

Can I write a function in Swift 5 that achieves the same result? I wrote this for one conversion, here's the example. If I can't write this function I will have this boilerplate code repeated throughout the app.

```
  public var intents: Set<Intent>
  if let jsonIntents = filters?["intent"] as? Array<String> {
     for jsonIntent in jsonIntents {
        if let intent = Intent(rawValue: jsonIntent) {
           intents.insert(intent)
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your enums are `RawRepresentable` with `RawValue == String`...

Enums in Swift don't have a special "base class" like `Enum`. But in this situation, we really just need to make use of their common property - both `RawRepresentable` and `Hashable`. Sure, lots of non-enums have this property, too. So our method will work on not just enums, but *any* type that conforms to these two protocols. That's rather nice isn't it?

```
func convertStringArrayToEnumSet<T>(type: T.Type, _ strings: [String]) -> Set<T> 
    where T : RawRepresentable & Hashable, T.RawValue == String {
    Set(strings.compactMap(T.init(rawValue:)))
}
```

Note the use of `compactMap`, which discards any invalid raw values.

In fact, you can generalise this to not just string arrays, but any array:

```
func convertRawValueArrayToEnumSet<T>(type: T.Type, _ rawValues: [T.RawValue]) -> Set<T> 
    where T : RawRepresentable & Hashable {
    Set(rawValues.compactMap(T.init(rawValue:)))
}
```

Comment: Simple, thanks! I assume that the call site looks like `type: Intent.self`? The Swift language "guide" doesnt mention `RawRepresentable` on the Enumerations page, and I'm not sure if Type.self is even discussed either. Still kind of rough to learn all of Swift's current tricks.

Comment: @androidguy Yes. The `.self` syntax is mentioned in the [Language _Reference_](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455), not the _Guide_. `RawRepresentable` is also mentioned in the reference, in [Enumeration Declarations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID364).

Answer (score 0):

Sweeper's answer is good, but I see you put some effort into error handling. Swift isn't good about helping you with that, so you have to make your own extensions.

(`Dictionary` and `RawRepresentable` are from Swift 1, which didn't have errors. They never got modernized, and just return optionals.)

```swift
/// Acts as a dictionary that `throw`s instead of returning optionals.
public protocol valueForKeyThrowingAccessor {
  associatedtype Key

  /// Should just be a throwing subscript, but those don't exist yet.
  func value<Value>(for: Key) throws -> Value
}
```

```swift
/// Acts as a dictionary.
public protocol valueForKeySubscript: valueForKeyThrowingAccessor {
  associatedtype Value

  subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get }
}

public extension valueForKeySubscript {
  /// - Throws: `KeyValuePairs<Key, Value>.AccessError.noValue`
  func value(for key: Key) throws -> Value {
    guard let value = self[key]
    else { throw KeyValuePairs<Key, Value>.AccessError.noValue(key: key) }

    return value
  }

  /// - Throws: `KeyValuePairs<Key, Value>.AccessError.typeCastFailure`
  func value<Value>(for key: Key) throws -> Value {
    guard let value = try value(for: key) as? Value
    else { throw KeyValuePairs<Key, Value>.AccessError.typeCastFailure(key: key) }

    return value
  }
}

extension Dictionary: valueForKeySubscript { }
```

```swift
public extension KeyValuePairs {
  /// An error throw from trying to access a value for a key.
  enum AccessError: Error {
    case noValue(key: Key)
    case typeCastFailure(key: Key)
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension RawRepresentable {
  /// Like `init(rawValue:)`, if it was throwing instead of failable.
  /// - Throws: `RawRepresentableExtensions<Self>.Error.invalidRawValue`
  /// if there is no value of the type that corresponds with the specified raw value.
  init(_ rawValue: RawValue) throws {
    guard let instance = Self(rawValue: rawValue)
    else { throw RawRepresentableExtensions<Self>.Error.invalidRawValue(rawValue) }

    self = instance
  }
}

/// A namespace for nested types within `RawRepresentable`.
public enum RawRepresentableExtensions<RawRepresentable: Swift.RawRepresentable> {
  public enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case invalidRawValue(RawRepresentable.RawValue)
  }
}

public extension InitializableWithElementSequence where Element: RawRepresentable {
  /// - Throws: `RawRepresentableExtensions<Element>.Error.invalidRawValue`
  init<RawValues: Sequence>(rawValues: RawValues) throws
  where RawValues.Element == Element.RawValue {
    self.init(
      try rawValues.map(Element.init)
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
/// A type that can be initialized with a `Sequence` of its `Element`s.
public protocol InitializableWithElementSequence: Sequence {
  init<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(_: Sequence)
  where Sequence.Element == Element
}

extension Array: InitializableWithElementSequence { }
extension Set: InitializableWithElementSequence { }
```

```swift
extension InitializableWithElementSequence where Element == Intent {
  init(filters: [String: Any]) throws {
    try self.init(
      rawValues: try filters.value(for: "intent") as [String]
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
try filters.map(Set.init)
```